# Section of script fails to hide on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

Me and my friends are trying to figure this out. The problem is that the class id call z fails to hide on page load completely. It shows a portion of z but we

expect all the contents in z including z it self to be hidden on page load and we want to push the button to see the whole z class but we are having problems doing that so how can we do that where it looks like this.

[GIF Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5M3G.gif)

We don't want it to look like this which looks like this currently.

[GIF Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tn3kk.gif)

**index.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var z = $('.z');
  var x = $('#x');
  
  var XHR = function() { output = "";
  $.getJSON("x.json", function(data) {
    $.each(data.shop, function(index, element) {
        for (var j in element) {
          output += element[j] + '<br>';
        }
      });
      x.html(output);
   });
};
  $("button").click(function(){ XHR(); });
z.show();
});
  </script>
  <style>
  h1 {
  color: gold;
}

#x {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.z {
  background-color: red;
  width: 250px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
display: none;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="z">
<h1>Details </h1>
<h2 id="x"></h2>
</div>
<button>Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**x.json**

```
{
        "shop": [{
                "item": "Ps3",
                "cost": "$150"
            },
            {
                "item": "xbox 360",
                "cost": "$140"
            },
            {
                "event": "Black Friday",
                "date": "4-25-2018"
            },
            {
                "special_guest": "John Doe",
                "time": "4:30 pm"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Please avoid abbreviations to improve legibility and write a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current code, display the Z class when loading the page and if I did not misunderstand try changing the program so:

```
$("button").click(function(){ XHR();});
z.show();
```

to so

```
$("button").click(function(){ 
  XHR();
  z.show();
});
```

or so if you want to see the Z class after the loading:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var z = $('.z');
  var x = $('#x');

  var XHR = function() { output = "";
  $.getJSON("x.json", function(data) {
    $.each(data.shop, function(index, element) {
        for (var j in element) {
          output += element[j] + '<br>';
        }
      });
      x.html(output);
      z.show(); // Show Z div!
   });
};
  $("button").click(function(){ XHR(); });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much Pinguto you don't know how much your solution is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your `z.show` should be placed within the button click handler.  That should solve your problem.

That is:

```
$("button").click(function(){ 
  XHR(); 
  z.show();
});
```